# Ethernet Transceiver Modem block scheme: 50:50 device in block scheme

Tags: ethernet, transceiver, block-diagram

This is a system architecture of the Optical Ethernet Transceiver Modem (OETM)
which allows a bidirectional transmission of optical signals and electrical signals (Ethernet). Given an optical input signal, the data can be transmitted over Ethernet and the optical output directly. A given Ethernet input is transformed into an optical output signal and also an Ethernet
output.

Does anyone know what "50:50" (red circle) is?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is a symbol for a 50:50 fiber coupler.  Assuming you are looking at this document:

https://www.arching.at/fileadmin/user_upload/redakteure/Forschungspreis/2020/Lamprecht_Christopher_Masterarbeit.pdf

They give the exact part number as the Thorlabs BXC15.